# iOS IAP product removal

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store, storekit

I am working on an app that has 2 IAP products and is on Apple Store. Both products unlock the same features, but one in for regular price and the other for "on sale" price.
The app combines both products and shows only one item on its store, this item displays both prices.

Now my client has decided to remove the "on sale" one, however while I have a development environment for the app, it doesn't seem to be the case for the IAP products. I guess my questions are:

- How do I test the new version if I cannot change the IAP product to Cleared For Sale = NO, since it would impact the current version in Apple Store? (there is no development/production IAP products)
- When a product is set to "Cleared for sale = NO" can the user still restore previous purchases?
- And what about if I delete that product?
- How to sync the release of new version (app X IAP products)?